# Duplicate key com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.artifact.BuildableArtifactImpl@7c139f68

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I have update my android studio to 3.2 canary8 .It throws an exception when configuring build.**Duplicate key com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.artifact.BuildableArtifactImpl@7c139f68**.Has anyone gotten this problem,and How to resolve it?

Comment: Gradle-plugin version 3.1.0 is ok. 3.2.0-alpha version do not work

Comment: It has been resolved just now!! There was a flavor named "main" in the productFlavors,and I changed it.It is working now

Answer (score 45, accepted):

change name "main" to another name in the productFlavors in build.gradle.

```
productFlavors {
    main {
        //...
    }
    qa {
        //...
    }
}
```

New format:

```
productFlavors {
    orginal {
        //...
    }
    qa {
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah,I have  resolved it with this method .Thanks all the way with you.

Comment: I am getting the error `Could not find method create() for arguments [crashlyticsStoreDeobsAppDebug, class com.crashlytics.tools.gradle.tasks.StoreMappingFileTask, com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.BuildArtifactsHolder$FinalBuildableArtifact@7013d5d7] on task set of type org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskContainer.`